# repair rmarkdown template errors

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have a project where I'm creating a powerpoint presentation with `rmarkdown` and `knitr`. Whenever I knit the presentation and open it, I get this error message.

[image: ppt error]

I used `pandoc`'s online tool [here](https://rmarkdown-office-template.herokuapp.com/?) to figure out what was wrong with my template, and received the following feedback.

[image: pandoc feedback]

How do I make the recommended repairs in the powerpoint? I was able to unzip the pptx using 7z and poke around the xml using `vscode`, but when I tried zipping it back up again it could not be read by powerpoint.

A minimal example appears below which produces the same errors as my bigger RMD. The template file I am using is one provided by my company. Rmarkdown is using pandoc version **2.11.4** .

````r
    ---
    title: "template_test"
    author: "D. Author"
    date: "6/30/2021"
    output: 
      powerpoint_presentation:
        reference_doc: template.pptx
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
    
    
    # clean global environment
    rm(list=ls())
    gc()
    
    ```
    
    ## Slide with R Output
    
    ```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
    summary(cars)
    ```
    
    ## Slide with Plot
    
    ```{r pressure}
    plot(pressure)
    ```
````

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Rmd file to create a pptx file? You can share a concise one. What is your Rmarkdown and pandoc version? The following link would tell you [how to check the pandoc version available with R session](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/pandoc_available.html).

Comment: Hi @CarlosLuisRivera , minimal example and pandoc version added to OP per your request, thanks for any help you can offer. I _think_ I just need help finding where in the xml to make the changes the pandoc website requests, and help re-compressing the file, but any insights you have on the RMD itself would be great.

Comment: I can't comment because I have no reputation yet, however, I have the same problem with a template that is functionally perfect according to the template checking tool. So I think you might be barking up the wrong tree looking to fix your template - I'm currently looking at my header and plot formatting.

Comment: hi @Paige , as best as I can tell , the `type` indicators that uniquely label objects in the presentation template. When you unzip the PPTX (e.g., https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/extract-files-or-objects-from-a-powerpoint-file-85511e6f-9e76-41ad-8424-eab8a5bbc517) and then view the contents, you can see some of these `type` keys, but which should be modified are unclear. Searching by the name the PANDOC tool indicates is incorrect helped with 1-2, but there were many more that aren't obvious.

Comment: @M.Wood, did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: @elliot thanks for checking in. Unfortunately no, this issue is still outstanding. Have moved on from the company that I was doing that work for, so at this point even if a recommendation did come along I no longer have access to the template in question.

Answer (score -2):

I tried changing part of your header by deleting the part corresponding to **reference_doc: template.pptx** and it generated a Powerpoint with the same name as the RMarkdown. I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for. I understand that the versions of Rmarkdown and Pandoc are superior to the ones indicated [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html).

The header would look like this:

```
---
title: "template_test"
author: "D. Author"
date: "6/30/2021"
output: powerpoint_presentation
---
```

Comment: hi @Lykansito, I am explicitly referencing a template file in that header. An example of that in action can be found here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html#ppt-templates